# Login to Twitter using requests

Tags: python, twitter, python-requests

I am trying to login to Twitter with `requests` module in Python (2.7), and after I am logged in, I want to visit another directory on Twitter.

So:

1. Visit: https://twitter.com/login
2. Locate username/pass elements
3. Input Twitter Credentials
4. Visit: https://twitter.com/settings/your_twitter_data
5. Input Twitter Password

My code so far:

```
import requests
import sys
import os

#LOGIN
data = {"session[username_or_email]":"MY_USERNAME",
    "session[password]":"MY_PASSWORD"}
r = requests.post("https://twitter.com/login/", data=data)

if ("success" in r.json()):
    print "Logged in successfully!"
else:
    print "Failed to login!"
    sys.exit(0)

#CHANGE URL AND INPUT PASSWORD
data = {"auth_password":"MY_PASSWORD"}
r = requests.post("https://twitter.com/settings/your_twitter_data", data=data)

if ("success" in r.json()):
    print "Success!"
    sys.exit(0)
```

When run, this is the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "twitter.py", line 10, in <module>
    if ("success" in r.json()):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 808, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/simplejson/__init__.py", line 516, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/simplejson/decoder.py", line 373, in decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end, len(s))
simplejson.scanner.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 5 - line 1 column 81 (char 4 - 80)
```

Comment: Looks like you're trying to convert the output to json (which is not a string), and the format is not JSON.

Comment: Perhaps you want to try https://pypi.python.org/pypi/twython a python twitter API wrapper instead of using requests.

Comment: There is way more involved when logging into Twitter

Comment: How to login? What all parameters should we add?

Comment: If you look at [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48479671/10668202), you will find the answer. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You are using `r.json()` though response is HTML, try `r.text` instead.

Also if you want to know you are successfully logged in, you'd rather check for your profile picture or something alike.

Then, you should use `requests.Session()`, more info there : http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/

Comment: I replaced r.json() with r.text but I got:   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "twitter.py", line 10, in <module>
    if ("success" in r.text()):
TypeError: 'unicode' object is not callable

Comment: `r.text`, not `r.text()`

Comment: Okay, but I keep getting "Failed to login!"... How should I check if I am logged in? For example, if title == "Twitter" ? How would I do this in requests though?

Comment: log in to twitter with your browser, right click your picture, click inspect and get the full url.
Now in your code, after the request try something like : `if r.text.find('yourPictureUrl') != -1: #logged in.`

Comment: I have checked with if URL == "https://twitter.com", print "worked" etc., but it seems like it doesn't login. It inputs the credentials but doesn't submit them. How do I submit them?

Comment: why don't you use twitter API? would be much easier.

Comment: Because I am not familiar with it. If you can re-write the whole code if you want for me, that would be nice..