# Getting 200 response but not logging in using python requests library

Tags: python, post, twitter, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I have tried to scrape twitter account followers list. For that, authentication is required. So i used requests library for authentication purpose. The problem i am getting is, when i try to authenticate, I am getting 200 response but authentication is not done. The code is:

```
    import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
payload={
"session[username_or_email]":"*****************",
"session[password]":"**********************",
"authenticity_token":"aa3520020157738bdabb6d60f2e02894c6c85689",
"ui_metrics":'{"rf":{"a67dd0828000993f688a64a8238f647dd8ef987feb0db5979725fc7e304c3989":-250,"a4cd98aa5fd1d026bfded286fc24eb6ac9cf01a65b789ade51b68558cb0f6ae0":-21,"a88c7b5bdeb04ce3cf55df08c0f981f99df760b9348680c735fbff5b60ad054f":51,"a5e59c69fb04ab30f2f8468030c31ca1150f4265e4c2a35dbb1b67b85be6954f":-68},"s":"QdcvZJ9RhjLcVcW2N_pDt5j5AKQJCkqnh9caYV5ykW35tRpQc_RN5s_VefN2uVCONpXf-qZa-fr8VtCAFrtiOf2f6PhloU2GyxLDN38wGppFNWhb4psCr7x-kibioS9PDxWZF1pe3FM-MOz9YtIQrWxbmEAWnRTK3gUn-1nv4kTFDa159YxJoXiYt43g41sRUJWezJI2yJaECnO1ARbkNAPKrMndxRAcq_5qSFpT8CqzEUvBKPMdFMKeUrzeEecqmx632lTV1NlucVIvV9co3Y3Rk7CtURoaiCwsjTED1brU4XAY3VwsTEuNRUYZqirRNZrYQBCHqsMh5FV_UHpO2QAAAWE40pmN"}',
"scribe_log":"",
"redirect_after_login":"",
"authenticity_token":"aa3520020157738bdabb6d60f2e02894c6c85689",
"return_to_ssl":"",
"remember_me":"1",
"lang":"",
"redirect":""
}
headers={
"accept":"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8",
"accept-encoding":"gzip, deflate, br",
"accept-language":"en-US,en;q=0.9",
"cache-control":"max-age=0",
"cookie":'moments_profile_moments_nav_tooltip_self=true; syndication_guest_id=v1%3A150345116906281638; eu_cn=1; kdt=QErLcBT9OjM5gjEznmsRcHlMTK6biDyAw4gfI5ro; _ga=GA1.2.1923324433.1496571570; tfw_exp=0; __utma=43838368.1923324433.1496571570.1516764481.1516764481.1; __utmz=43838368.1516764481.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); remember_checked_on=0; personalization_id="v1_Iq7dc3Mq746/e91mchhhJg=="; guest_id=v1%3A151698504007256847; ads_prefs="HBERAAA="; _twitter_sess=BAh7CSIKZmxhc2hJQzonQWN0aW9uQ29udHJvbGxlcjo6Rmxhc2g6OkZsYXNo%250ASGFzaHsABjoKQHVzZWR7ADoPY3JlYXRlZF9hdGwrCF5%252F0jhhAToMY3NyZl9p%250AZCIlN2ZmZjExM2NkYjUzODEzZDNiNDE4YWI3NGRhZTAxOTc6B2lkIiU3YWFl%250AZjVhNDY1OWJlNzdiN2RiYjEzNjIwYWVjMGMyMQ%253D%253D--d69792331ec3a3b6c9d994a07f2159bfd5697089; ct0=ecc095f3a61b1c77279538584cb6f20e; _gid=GA1.2.253357133.1517076775; _gat=1',
"referer":"https://twitter.com/login",
"upgrade-insecure-requests":"1",
"user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36"
}
str=payload["ui_metrics"]
x=json.dumps(str)
y=json.loads(str)
payload["ui_metrics"]=y
res = requests.post("https://twitter.com/login",data=payload,headers=headers)
r = requests.get("https://twitter.com/following")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"html.parser")
print(res.status_code)
print(r.url)
print(soup.prettify())
for item in soup.find_all({"class":"u-textInheritColor js-nav"}):
    print(item.text)
```

I am getting 200 response for status code. How to solve this problem?
**NOTE:** I am not using any APIs. I want to authenticate using requests library.

Comment: The issue is Twitter login route needs to return to you a token, and you need to use said token to fetch the data...

Comment: You can't just reuse old tokens, no. Do a GET request *first*, parse the HTML form, extract the token set there, use a `requests.session()` object to maintain cookies and only *then* post your login.

Comment: Not sure why you are using `json.dumps()` then `json.loads()` on the `ui_metrics` string. That's all a useless dance wasting your CPU cycles. You converted a string to a JSON string, then decoded the JSON string to produce... the original string you already had.

Comment: One of my friends suggested me to pass "ui_metrics" as json format. SO i did in that way

Comment: That token is used when we try tweepy API right? @MikeTung

Comment: I have no idea what that `tweepy` is. It's an access token to get data from twitter api. I highly recommend using the twitter library because it will save you from all this pain.

Comment: In page source, `<input type="hidden" name="return_to_ssl" value="true">`, so shouldn't it be `'return_to_ssl': 'true'`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this. It should get you there:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with requests.Session() as s:
    r = s.get("https://twitter.com/login")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")

    token = soup.select_one("[name='authenticity_token']")['value']

    payload={
    'session[username_or_email]':'your_email',
    'session[password]':'your_password',
    'authenticity_token':token,
    'ui_metrics':'{"rf":{"c6fc1daac14ef08ff96ef7aa26f8642a197bfaad9c65746a6592d55075ef01af":3,"a77e6e7ab2880be27e81075edd6cac9c0b749cc266e1cea17ffc9670a9698252":-1,"ad3dbab6c68043a1127defab5b7d37e45d17f56a6997186b3a08a27544b606e8":252,"ac2624a3b325d64286579b4a61dd242539a755a5a7fa508c44eb1c373257d569":-125},"s":"fTQyo6c8mP7d6L8Og_iS8ulzPObBOzl3Jxa2jRwmtbOBJSk4v8ClmBbF9njbZHRLZx0mTAUPsImZ4OnbZV95f-2gD6-03SZZ8buYdTDkwV-xItDu5lBVCQ_EAiv3F5EuTpVl7F52FTIykWowpNIzowvh_bhCM0_6ReTGj6990294mIKUFM_mPHCyZxkIUAtC3dVeYPXff92alrVFdrncrO8VnJHOlm9gnSwTLcbHvvpvC0rvtwapSbTja-cGxhxBdekFhcoFo8edCBiMB9pip-VoquZ-ddbQEbpuzE7xBhyk759yQyN4NmRFwdIjjedWYtFyOiy_XtGLp6zKvMjF8QAAAWE468LY"}',
    'scribe_log':'',
    'redirect_after_login':'',
    'authenticity_token':token,
    'remember_me':1
    }
    headers={
    'accept':'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
    'content-type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'origin':'https://twitter.com',
    'referer':'https://twitter.com/login',
    'upgrade-insecure-requests':'1',
    'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36'
    }
    res = s.post("https://twitter.com/sessions",data=payload,headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
    for item in soup.select(".tweet-text"):
        print(item.text)
```